# Installation of gcc on hpux

Tags: bash, software-installation, python, compiling, dependencies

I need to install `libffi-3.2.1-ia64_64-11.31.depot.gz` on a hp-ux server. To install that I need the build-time dependencies `make` and `gcc`.  I have installed `make` (64 bit) but I cannot find the `gcc` (64 bit) depot file.

http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Gnu/gcc-4.2.3/

**Questions:**

- Where can I get the `gcc` depot for 64 bit?
- What is difference between run-time dependencies and build-time dependencies?

Ultimately I am trying to install python `2.7.8` and now I am fixing its dependencies.

**Run-time dependencies:**

```
bzip2   expat   gdbm    gettext libffi  libiconv    libunistring    ncurses openssl
readline    sqlite  zlib
```

**Build-time dependencies:**

```
bzip2   expat   gdbm    gettext libffi  libiconv    libunistring    make    ncurses
openssl readline    sqlite  zlib
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing from a depot file, you'll only need the run-time dependencies.

Build-time dependencies are only needed if you wish to *rebuild the depot from the source code*, e.g. to produce a newer version of it.

You can even compile new programs that use `libffi` with only run-time dependencies for it installed.

The instructions available with the "Installation" button at http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Development/Libraries/libffi-3.2.1/ refer to compiling the package from source code. If you're using a depot file, you won't need to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much.. That helps..

Comment: gcc dependency was in build time dependency so I did not install..

Comment: another one is .. I was able to install python and pip.. but when I try to install any package through pip.. I am getting below error message... Any suggestions would be helpful..   # python -V
Python 2.7.18
# pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: pip install cx_Freeze==5.0
Collecting cx_Freeze==5.0
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x9fffffffee9fa410>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 229] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/cx-freeze/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cx_Freeze==5.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cx_Freeze==5.0